# Google SignIn and FCM Push Notification with same JSON

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have implemented SignIn with Google in my app by using this [guideline](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating). It was working fine.

Now, I integrated Firebase Notifications in my app and definitely, my Google configuration file is changed. I am using this code to sign in:

```
  GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestId()
            .requestIdToken("server-client-id")
            .requestServerAuthCode("server-client-id")
            .requestProfile()                
            .build();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use a single configuration file for FCM and Google SignIn (not through FCM)?

Comment: Try implementing Google SignIn from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Generate FCM google-service.json file and merge with existing and place it on root folder So you can access one json file for both services.